# How do use one value in a table to replace another value in the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains codes (i.e. 8202-6) and has a resulting value in a different column.   I used the "Case When" function to take the codes out a single column and place them in separate columns based on the code number.   However, now I end up with a bunch of null values in the rows and one code with one result.   I would like to replace the actual code with it's corresponding value (i.e. 8206-6 = Height, result 75).   So in the Height column I get the LOINC code instead of the Height value of 75.   Can anyone help me figure out the right code to use.   Below is an example of the code that I'm using just to get the columns separated.

```
Select Distinct

p.PatientID,
Convert(varchar, fs.obsdate, 101) as Date_of_Service,
p.LASTNAME,
p.FIRSTNAME,
CONVERT(varchar, "p"."DATEOFBIRTH", 101) as DOB,
Case When fs.loinccode='8302-2' Then fs.loinccode end as Height,
Case When fs.loinccode='3141-9' Then fs.loinccode end as Weight,
Case When fs.loinccode='8310-5' Then fs.loinccode end as Temperature,
Case When fs.loinccode='8287-5' Then fs.loinccode end as HeadCircumf,
Case When fs.loinccode='8867-4' Then fs.loinccode end as Pulse,
Case When fs.loinccode='9279-1' Then fs.loinccode end as Respiration,
Case When fs.loinccode='8480-6' Then fs.loinccode end as BPSystolic,
Case When fs.loinccode='8462-4' Then fs.loinccode end as BPDiastolic,
fs.obsvalue as Test_Results,
fs.units as Test_Units

From

PERSON as p 
Left Outer join flowsheet_observation fs on fs.pid=p.pid
```

Result:

```
Height  Weight  Temperature HeadCircumf Pulse   Respiration BPSystolic  BPDiastolic Test_Results    Test_Units
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    + history of lef tshoulder dislocation 10 years ago    Current Meds:        NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    never   NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    regular NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    tympanic    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    8462-4  100 mm Hg
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    8480-6  NULL    140 mm Hg
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    8867-4  NULL    NULL    NULL    82  /min
NULL    NULL    8310-5  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    99.1    deg F
NULL    3141-9  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    283 lb
8302-2  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    72.5    in
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    37.72   NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    regular NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    tympanic    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    8462-4  100 mm Hg
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    8480-6  NULL    142 mm Hg
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    8867-4  NULL    NULL    NULL    86  /min
NULL    NULL    8310-5  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    99.4    deg F
NULL    3141-9  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    281 lb
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a table code_names which relates the codes with their meaning,

```
code   | label
8302-2 | Height
3141-9 | Weight
...
```

then join flowsheet_observation with it and select label instead of code. No need for all those cases.

Edit: if creating a table of codes is not an option, the relation of codes can be created with a union:

SELECT '8302-2' AS code, 'Height' AS label
UNION
SELECT '3141-9' AS code, 'Weight' AS label
UNION
...

Comment: Thanks you for the feedback, however, what if I only have the ability to query the data and unable to create, modify, or edit the existing table?

Comment: But now that I think about it, I can create a view which will not disturb the data in the existing table or interfere with the front end program. On the other hand, a view can't be created without querying the existing table.

Comment: you can use a union to create a table on the fly. How many codes do you have?

Answer (score 0):

TRY used MAX(CASE WHEN THEN END)
AND group by other fields

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Column 'flowsheet_observation.obsdate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: flowsheet_observation.obsdate include this field in GROUP BY clause